# Get all posts in Facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all birthday posts in my facebook wall.
I'm using Facebook graph Api and i'm saving posts by sending request for feed.
Instead of getting all the posts made on my wall .i'm getting only one post saying 
41 friends posted on your wall with list last 3 posts.
How can i get all 41 posts using facebook graph api

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=access_token, version='2.5')
profile = graph.get_object('me')
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'feed', limit=500)
```

Comment: You can't. Why do you need them?

Comment: im working on auto comment script .I need post ids of all posts but i'm getting only recent 3 posts

Comment: Auto comment script is not allowed so it doesn't matter